# Calculate checksum in BizTalk Orchestration Expression shape

Tags: cryptography, md5, biztalk, biztalk-orchestrations, biztalk-2020

In an orchestration I need to find out if I already processed a message before and,if so, I must ignore it for further processing. I thought I might be able to calculate checksom on the message to get a unique value, like an MD5 checksum.

How can I easily trigger such calculation for a message in an orchestration?

Comment: Create a helper class that you call from the Orchestration.  You would also need to persist that checksum somewhere so you can check if it has been received before.  An alternative to checksums is to just use key fields to create a unique identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to create a helper class with checksum calculation, also for storing and comparing checksums.